# Color calibration not working in 10.04.4 with GNOME Color Manager

Tags: 10.04, nvidia, gnome, color-management, dualhead

Calibrating my monitors, or loading a different icc profile, does not affect the color representation on my monitor.

System setup:
PC:                     MD8822 dual core.
OS:                     Ubuntu 10.04.4 desktop 64 bits.
Calibration software:   Gnome color manager.
Calibration device:     Huey Pro.
Monitor 1:              Eizo Flexscan L887.
Monitor 2:              Prolite E1900S.
GPU                     GeForce 7650 GS.
Driver:                 Nvidia 302.17.

I have the Nvidia driver configured in twin view mode.

When I change the profile in the color manager, the monitor shows some flickering lines for about half a second, but the colors do not change. The color profiles are definitely different.

I just installed 10.04.4 and choose the 302.17 driver as this gave me the best results for my dual head set up.

Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

After trying many things I found out that there is a checkbox on the tab defaults which says "Apply Display Correction".

On one hand, I feel silly that I didn't notice this before; on the other hand, the system layout is, at the least, not intuitive.

Anyway, I'm happy that I can finally calibrate my displays again!

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade the Nvidia driver. I get the same issues with the 302 on Ubuntu 12.04, but the 295 is still able to use the calibration profile.

I am using the 295 build from the x-swat ppa :- https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates/+builds?build_text=&build_state=all

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates?field.series_filter=oneiric

It is possible you will only be able to load a single calibration profile.

Comment: Anonymous comment: EDIT - It seems you can use the 302 with dispwin if you disable xrandr. Since the later 302 drivers are supposed to have the support for xrandr that was missing, I'm not sure whether that would be considered progress(Maybe it is if you have a single monitor :)):- http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=181410